# netlify is not able to recognise ng while deploying angular project

Tags: angular, deployment, build, netlify

I am trying to deploy an Angular project on Netlify but get the below error:

[image]

Here are my scripts from `package.json`:

[image]

Here are my Netlify build settings:

[image]

Here is my `outputPath` from `angular.json`:

[image]

Comment: Is `@angular/cli` a dependency? Are the dependencies getting installed correctly?

Comment: yes it is, I even upgraded it

Comment: I reinstalled the packages several times using npm install and it seems ok

Comment: I am able to build locally, it is successful but with some warnings, i am not sure if this is the reasoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broblem is solved, i was setting the npm version in the deployments setting > environment variables,  once i removed it the deploy was successful, also i set the ci variable to false